# Refetch works in unexpected ways with useInfiniteQuery (react-query)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm implementing an infinite list of items with React-Query (v3), and when the user deletes one I want  to refetch all pages but it's not working as expected. Let me explain it after showing some code.

```
function useUserWatchlist({
  userId,
  pageNumber = 1,
  pageSize = 24,
  queryOptions,
}) {

  const userList = useInfiniteQuery(
    ['watchlist', userId],
    async ({ pageParam = pageNumber }) => await fetchUserWatchlist(userId, pageParam, pageSize),
    {
      getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => {
        let nextPage = null;

        if (lastPage.pagination.pageNumber < lastPage.pagination.totalPages) {
          nextPage = lastPage.pagination.pageNumber + 1;
        }

        return nextPage;
      },
      getPreviousPageParam: (firstPage) => {
        let previousPage = null;

        if (firstPage.pagination.pageNumber > 0) {
          previousPage = firstPage.pagination.pageNumber - 1;
        }

        return previousPage;
      },
      ...queryOptions,
    }
  );

   const {
    data,
    isLoading,
    isError,
    error,
    isSuccess,
    hasNextPage,
    hasPreviousPage,
    isRefetching,
    isFetchingNextPage,
    fetchNextPage,
    fetchPreviousPage,
    refetch,
  } = userList;

  let watchlistResultsDTO = {};

  if (!isLoading && !isError) {
    watchlistResultsDTO = {
      pageData: data?.pages.map((page, index) => {
        return {
          [`page${index + 1}`]: page?.items,
        };
      }),
      totalPages: data?.pages?.[0].pagination?.totalPages,
    };
  }

  return {
    data: watchlistResultsDTO,
    isLoading,
    isError,
    error,
    isSuccess,
    hasNextPage,
    hasPreviousPage,
    isFetchingNextPage,
    fetchNextPage,
    fetchPreviousPage,
    refetch,
    isRefetching,
  };
}
```

Mutate Hook:

```
 const { isLoading: isLoadingRemovingContent, mutate: removeContent } =
    useMutation({
      mutationFn: ({ userId, contentId }) =>
        removeFromUserWatchlist(userId, contentId),
      onSuccess: () => {

        queryClient.cancelQueries({
          queryKey: ['watchlist', userId],
          exact: true,
          refetchActive: false,
          refetchInactive: false,
        });

        queryClient.refetchQueries(['watchlist', userId], {
          exact: true,
          active: true,
          inactive: true,
        });

        onContentRemoved && onContentRemoved();
      },
    });
```

You can see after deleting I cancel the queries and then I refetch. When I console log the data in OnSucces (the hook mutation) I can see the pageParams are: [undefined, 2, 3, 4]. But the queryFn of the Inifite hook always starts one page before the last and it makes the requests of pages items?pageSize=24&pageNumber=3, items?pageSize=24&pageNumber=4, items?pageSize=24&pageNumber=5 (pages 3,4,5). Can anyone help me or give me an insight for this issue?

I already tried with queryClient.invalidateQueries and it's the same behavior

pd: In the example above it can continue querying because the total pages are 6, but if not it starts it will re estart querying from 1.